# perl regex - trying to capture partial string into new var

Tags: regex, perl

I have a long string and I'm trying to capture 2 values out of it.
My original string:

```
$string = 'content' => '{"sender":"xxx.xxx@icloud.com","location":"Beacon","event":"LocationTest","time":"2014-11-20 03:24:19 +0000"}',
             'auto_upgrade' => 1,
             'max_memory_size' => 262144
```

I would like to have the location "Beacon" in a var called `$location` and the event "LocationTest" in a var called `$event`
The titles "location": and "event": will always appear in my string. Any easy way to do this with regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex of the form

for location:

```
/(?<="location":)"[^"]*"/
```

for event

```
/(?<="event":)"[^"]*"/
```

Example code:

```
$str='"sender":"xxx.xxx@icloud.com","location":"Beacon","event":"LocationTest","time":"2014-11-20
03:24:19 +0000"';

$str =~ m/(?<="location":)("[^"]*")/;
print 'Location ',$1;
$str =~ m/(?<="event":)("[^"]*")/;
print 'event ',$1;
```

Will produce an output

```
Location "Beacon"
event "LocationTest"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=location":")([^"]+)|(?<=event":")([^"]+)
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the captures.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/40

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JSON, which means you'd be much better off in the long run by using a module such as [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS).